# How to Create a Lab Beaker "Spout" in Houdini?

Tags: houdini

I have created a basic beaker geometry. Now I want to create the beaker spout, but have no idea on how to procedurally:

- Slice the geometry where the spout needs to be placed
- Bend / transform the sliced area in the shape of a spout

[Beaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcjmT.png)

[Nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91vld.png)

[Spout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsooC.png)

Please assist. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.